# How to reference other environment properties inside of environment.ts file in Angular project?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to modify the 'environment.ts' file in Angular project and add some additional properties to it. What I have is:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://example.com',
  authApiUrl: 'http://example.com/auth'
};
```

The question is if it's possible to somehow unify it and reference other properties so that it looked something like:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://example.com',
  authApiUrl: apiUrl + '/auth'
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about using a constant for this type of thing. Like below.

```
const apiBase = 'http://example.com';

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: apiBase,
  authApiUrl: apiBase + '/auth'
};
```

Should give you the results you expect. Works for me in my CLI applications to get more DRY.

Comment: But how apiBase = 'http://example.com' can be parametrized from the outside, then? If we are willing `http://example.com` to become `http://definitive.com` without releasing another version of the application, how do we do? We loose the ability to change the value of  apiUrl later by making it a constant, the opposite of the environment goal.